# Отправка сообщений с Hangfire

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

Покажите пожалуйста какой пример отправки сообщений на Email с технологией Hangfire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам нужен будет Postal из NuGet, 
Создайте класс:

```
using Postal;

namespace Hangfire.Mailer.Models
{
    public class NewCommentEmail : Email
    {
        public string To { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

А это пример контроллера:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Comment model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.Comments.Add(model);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        var email = new NewCommentEmail
        {
            To = "yourmail@example.com",
            UserName = model.UserName,
            Comment = model.Text
        };

        email.Send();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

[Здесь](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/tutorials/send-email.html#installing-postal) все подробно описано...